# ServiceStack and MVC4 not wiring up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I have an existing MVC 4 application. I wanted to add Service Stack to it. I tried installing the MVC host nuget package:

Install-Package ServiceStack.Host.Mvc

It installed 2 files in App_Start. I noticed I had to make a slight change because I was getting a build error:

In App_State/WebServiceExamples.cs, I had to update the interface references:

From: `public class HelloService : Service`

To: `public class HelloService : ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service`

I then went ahead and double checked the Web.config settings:

```
<location path="api">
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

I then ran the application and went to /api, I got a 404. From some further research I decided to manually update the endpoint via the apphost file:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
{
ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api",
});
```

This also didn't seem to work. What else am I missing?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be in your web.config file as well:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="api*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Also don't forget to **remove** the MVC '/api' route/path. You need to remove it so that ServiceStack and MVC don't compete for the '/api' route/path.

```
//REMOVE THIS FROM RouteConfig
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
);
```

If you want to be real explicit you can also add this to the RouteConfig

```
routes.IgnoreRoute ("api/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: Added routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}"); to the RegisterRoutes routine in Global.asax.cs did the trick. If you are having this issue, be sure to add it before you register your default route or any other routes.

Comment: @Gordon Note: this info is also included in the NuGet project's [ReadMe.txt](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/NuGet/ServiceStack.Host.Mvc/content/README.txt) file.